# How to use php array+string in html?

Tags: php, html, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I am using PL/pgsql `RETURNS TABLE` to get the below output using `pg_fetch_all` in PHP

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> array(1) 
    { ["not_actual_values"]=> string(88) "("var1","var2",var3,var4,date1,int,int,int,var5,int,int,int,int)" } 
[1]=> array(1) 
    { ["not_actual_values"]=> string(89) "("var1","var2",var3,var4,date1,int,int,int,var5,int,int,int,int)" } 
[2]=> array(1) 
    { ["not_actual_values"]=> string(88) "("var1","var2",var3,var4,date1,int,int,int,var5,int,int,int,int)" } 
[3]=> array(1) 
    { ["not_actual_values"]=> string(89) "("var1","var2",var3,var4,date1,int,int,int,var5,int,int,int,int)" } 
}
```

I am unable to use the above output in HTML. I tried using *php explode* but it didnt work I got *zero* array. Also, What confuses me I am getting quotes in first two variable and not in others.

**Update**

I used below function but I got *zero* array

```
function pgArrayToPhp($text) {
    if(is_null($text)) {
        return array();
    } else if(is_string($text) && $text != '{}') {
        $text = substr($text, 1, -1);// Removes starting "{" and ending "}"
        if(substr($text, 0, 1) == '"') {
            $text = substr($text, 1);
        }
        if(substr($text, -1, 1) == '"') {
            $text = substr($text, 0, -1);
        }
        // If double quotes are present, we know we're working with a string.
        if(strstr($text, '"')) { // Assuming string array.
            $values = explode('","', $text);
        } else { // Assuming Integer array.
            $values = explode(',', $text);
        }
        $fixed_values = array();
        foreach($values as $value) {
            $value = str_replace('\\"', '"', $value);
            $fixed_values[] = $value;
        }
        return $fixed_values;
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Please make your code easier to read please. Like new lines for 1 command

Comment: Share your code. It's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I need to use above output in html table. I need to use **each** variable in separate columns. Right now I get them in one column.

Comment: It may be more reliable to parse your 'value' string as CSV. PHP has a function for this that you may find useful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php. I haven't tried this.

Comment: Hang on, you're trying to decode `var_dump()` output? Why?

Comment: @jack I am **not** decoding var_dump output rather I am using **the output to the data** which I need to use in html table. I have also put up code which I tried to use but was unable to get desired. so How this is offtopic I fail to understand.

Comment: @vedic I am sure `ph_fetch_all` won't return this string. Iterate over returned array properly. :)

Comment: @vedic Can you `print_r($text)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that I have come up with. Though it is *not neat* but it seems to be working as expected now

```
$fetch=pg_fetch_all($query); //fetching data from postgresql
$count=count($fetch);
for ($j=0;$j<$count;$j++) {
$a = $fetch[$j]['not_actual_values'];
$b = array(explode("," , $a)); 
$count2=count($b[0]);
foreach ($b as $f) { echo '<tr>';
for ($i=0;$i<$count2;$i++){
echo '<td><input type="text" readonly value='.$f[$i].'>';
}   }   }
```

But now the problem is raw data contains noise as in `"("` so that is spoiling the output.

Thank you all for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner values are arrays, not strings, you need to take that into account:

```
function pgArraytoPhp($array) {
     foreach ($array as $row) {      // $row is an inner array here!
         actuallyDoParsing($row[0]); // Parse row's first element, 
                                     // which will be the string you want.
     }
}
```

Depending on what you need, you'll return the accumulated result of all of those `actuallyDoParsing()` calls.